# Difference between 'application access token' and 'application user access token'

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, wso2

In WSO2 API Manager there are 2 token types, application access & user access tokens according to documentation.It is clear that application access token is used to access the set of APIs subscribed via a application in APIM.

What is the meaning of application user access token? How do we subscribe APIs to a particular user(not a application) via APIM? Does APIM provide a GUI to manage 'application user' tokens/subscribed APIs? Does the application user need to register in the APIM same as the application developer ?

I'm confused what is the scenario of using application user access token..

Also, what are the oauth2 types used in generating these 2 types of tokens seperately?

Answer (score 0):

Application Token- This is a security token and we can use it to call APIs (bundled into application)
Wso2 also supports the generation of access tokens on demand through a specific login API. In case of tokens expire, access tokens can be re-generate through this login API. For generation of access tokens, the login API takes 4 parameters:

Grant Type

Username

Password

Scope

Comment: Hi,according to documentation https://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Working+with+Access+Tokens it says, 'User access tokens are generated at user-level and valid for all APIs subscribed to a user' . Im just confused how a user can subscribe to a API via APIM? GUI seems providing only subscribing APIs to a application only..

Comment: Are you using the WSO2 API Manager 1.6.0?

Comment: I am using the latest version

Comment: 1.The newly added API would be available in the API store for subscription. When a developer subscribes to this API, it would be added to the subscribed application list in the subscriber’s API Store. Even though the API is subscribed by the user, the API Manager will not allow it to be consumed until admin approves the subscription. The API icon in the subscribed API section would be in gray-scaled indicating that the API is yet to be approved by the admin function. The below image shows a subscribed API that is yet to be approved by admin.